# Accessing files using MPI

Tags: file-io, compiler-errors, parallel-processing, mpi

THIS WORKED (see comment in the code)

I am new to MPI and still learning it. I am actually trying to write a code in Fortran to read data from same set of files (already generated) on each processor at same time and perform different computations in different processors. For which I decided to use,

program...

```
use mpi

implicit none
.
.
.

call mpi_file_open(mpi_comm_world,filename_i,mpi_mode_rdonly,mpi_info_null,i,ierr)
```

to start with the program. Now, each processor calls a subroutine in which I am trying to use normal fortran command to open files, `open(i,*)`...(since I don't use mpi in subroutine).

First, I am not confident about this idea itself. Next, it gives this error,

```
_open(mpi_comm_world,filename_i,mpi_mode_rdonly,mpi_status_ignore,i,ierr) (1)
```

> Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic 'mpi_file_open'
>   at (1)

Please give your suggestions and comments.

---

The thing I am trying to do is very long because of subroutine, I would just include a prototype code, if this is solved, my problem will be solved. The code below gives the same error as said before. Please give your suggestions. Thanks.

```
program hello  
use mpi  
integer::ierr,num_procs,my_id,i,j,no  

call MPI_INIT(ierr)  
call MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD,my_id,ierr)    
call MPI_COMM_SIZE (MPI_COMM_WORLD,num_size,ierr)  
open(4,file='hella') !CHANGING THIS LINE  
do i=1,num_size  
   if(i-1 .eq. my_id)print*,"In",my_id  
   if(i-1 .eq. my_id)then  
      read(4,*)no  
      print*,no  
   endif  
enddo  

call mpi_finalize(ierr)  
end program hello
```

Comment: It's written [on the mpi-forum](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.0/mpi-20-html/node175.htm) that all processes must provide the same value for amode, and all processes must provide filenames that reference the same file. You should probably use `mpi_comm_self` if each process is opening his file.

Comment: I cant test anything because of that error, so can you please say something about that. Even mpi_comm_self gives same error - no specific subroutine.

Comment: You don't give enough source code to diagnose the problem, but the compile error is suggesting that the argument list has the wrong types.